# Estimating parameter covariance matrix when fitting a Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) model using 'extRemes' in R

Tags: r, data-fitting, estimation, covariance-matrix

My question is similar to [Error with fitting a Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) using `extRemes` in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620434/error-with-fitting-a-generalized-extreme-value-gev-using-extremes-in-r). However, I am fitting non-stationary Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) distribution, i.e., when the location parameter depends on covariates and is no longer a constant. I am also using `extRemes` package in R. The solution presented in the above post does not work in my case as the function (`EnvStats::egevd`) used in the solution does not work for non-stationary GEVs.

Since the origincal data is large, here is a subset of my data which gives me a warning that follows as a result of which it does not produce a matrix giving the parameter covariances.

```
library(extRemes)
y <-  c(4.844187, 4.844187, 4.174387, 4.744932, 4.094345, 4.174387, 4.343805, 4.624973,
  4.094345, 4.094345, 4.343805, 4.174387, 4.499810, 4.094345, 4.499810, 4.343805,
  4.653960, 4.499810, 4.941642, 4.624973, 4.499810, 4.744932, 4.317488, 4.499810,
  4.605170, 4.844187, 4.744932, 4.499810, 4.094345, 4.442651, 4.653960, 4.317488,
  4.744932, 4.174387, 4.605170, 4.700480, 4.744932, 4.553877, 4.248495, 4.094345,
  4.442651, 4.553877, 4.317488, 4.382027, 4.248495, 4.382027, 4.499810, 4.382027,
  4.382027, 4.382027, 4.248495, 4.248495, 4.248495, 4.382027, 4.248495, 4.744932,
  4.094345, 4.700480, 4.744932, 4.499810, 4.317488, 4.382027, 4.382027, 4.499810,
  4.248495, 4.499810, 4.382027, 4.700480, 4.653960, 4.744932, 4.605170, 4.094345,
  4.700480, 4.700480, 4.499810, 4.700480, 4.605170, 4.700480, 4.653960, 4.382027,
  4.499810, 4.174387, 4.174387, 4.174387, 4.499810, 4.382027, 4.553877, 4.499810,
  4.094345, 4.174387, 4.442651, 4.094345, 4.382027, 4.317488, 4.317488, 4.382027,
  4.442651, 4.442651, 4.174387, 4.094345)

x <-  c(4.535284, 4.556505, 3.305054, 4.293878, 3.228826, 3.375880, 3.562466, 4.047428,
   3.719651, 2.957511, 3.228826, 3.375880, 3.896909, 3.719651, 4.011868, 3.442019,
  4.208417, 3.812203, 4.617593, 4.011868, 3.766997, 4.397531, 3.504055, 4.114964,
  4.081766, 4.535284, 4.237723, 3.936716, 3.812203, 3.896909, 4.147095, 3.789855,
  4.293878, 3.305054, 4.147095, 4.147095, 4.293878, 3.896909, 3.644144, 3.562466,
  3.617652, 3.974998, 3.562466, 3.719651, 3.617652, 3.896909, 3.974998, 3.896909,
  4.147095, 3.766997, 3.695110, 3.695110, 3.695110, 3.896909, 3.504055, 4.480174,
  3.504055, 4.433789, 4.587515, 4.147095, 3.695110, 3.766997, 3.766997, 3.974998,
  3.695110, 4.081766, 3.896909, 4.421848, 4.347047, 4.587515, 4.421848, 3.504055,
  4.421848, 4.421848, 4.064744, 4.293878, 4.293878, 4.421848, 4.293878, 3.896909,
  4.193435, 3.766997, 3.504055, 3.644144, 4.064744, 3.974998, 4.147095, 4.064744,
  3.504055, 3.834061, 4.147095, 3.695110, 4.081766, 3.974998, 4.147095, 4.147095,
  4.266195, 4.223177, 3.812203, 3.504055)

fac <- as.factor(c(rep("a", 45), rep("b", 55)))

# Data 
dat <- data.frame(y = y, x= x, fac = fac)

# Non-stationary GEV model:
gev_mod <- fevd(dat$y, data = dat, location.fun = ~x*fac + I(x^2)*fac, 
    scale.fun=~1, shape.fun =~1, type = 'GEV')
```

Here is the output with the warning. Usually when you display the summary or the model output you get a matrix for covariances of parameters but in this case we don't.  Although we get the parameter estimates but I need the parameter covariance matrix for inference purposes and I am not able to figure out where the problem lies. The default estimation method used is MLE, but I tried other methods like the Generalized MLE (GMLE) as well and still had the same issue.  I am just starting out in the field and any help on how to fix this issue is much appreciated.

```
Warning messages:
1: In log(z) : NaNs produced
2: In log(z) : NaNs produced
3: In log(z) : NaNs produced
4: In log(z) : NaNs produced
5: In log(z) : NaNs produced
6: In log(z) : NaNs produced
7: In log(z) : NaNs produced
8: In log(z) : NaNs produced
> gev_mod

fevd(x = dat$y, data = dat, location.fun = ~x * fac + I(x^2) * 
    fac, scale.fun = ~1, shape.fun = ~1, type = "GEV")

[1] "Estimation Method used: MLE"


 Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  -114.3946 


 Estimated parameters:
       mu0        mu1        mu2        mu3        mu4        mu5      scale 
 5.5752723 -1.0508929 -2.3604995  0.1951670  1.0569155 -0.1229494  0.1034723 
     shape 
-0.7972565 

 AIC = -212.7893 

 BIC = -191.9479 
> summary(gev_mod$cov.theta)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way to solve the problem. I looked at the source code for the `fevd` function in the `extRemes` package and noticed that `log(z)` appeared in the `grlevd` function which is used to estimate the gradient of likelihood needed for estimation.  I used the `trace()` function in R to change the `log(z)` to `log1p(z)` and that seemed to have worked. Now I don't get any warnings and also get the estimated parameter covariance matrix.
Just a side note, having worked with EVDs over the past couple of days, it looks like convergence in optimization could be tricky, especially for the non-stationary models.